# What is the best approach for drawing and animating images on Android

Tags: android

Im experienced iOS dev but new to Android dev and asking some newbie questions here...

I have to make a app where I have a background image and I then place some other images on top of that, and also onto those images I have to place different "glow" images that flicker (opacity on/off), and I need good control on positioning all those images. Now there is not some high performance goal here, and its not many objects, its not really a game.

What is the best approach for this? Can I use ImageView's for this or will it be better to use a Surface and custom draw in a thread?

And please, what ever you suggest, can you give a link to a good tutorial on the approach (ImageView or custom draw), I need all the help I can on this project with its crazy deadline.

Thank you

Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience:

- if its mostly static you should stick to XML and stuff like ImageViews etc
- if its simple animations, the predefined android classes are fine and somewhat easy to use
- if you want real custom then drawing with canvas is the way to go

You can extend View and override the onDraw method or create a SurfaceView which has better performance but is not that easy to use.

(sorry i dont have any tutorial links)